# How to convert the string variable to Date format with UTC time zone?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
var string = "14/2/2018 6:00 pm";
```

How to convert the String variable to Date format with UTC Time zone?
i try this 
var x = moment.tz("16/2/2018 7:00 pm", "UTC").format();
output: x : Invalid Date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to date in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

Comment: take a look at Moment JS

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this format while parsing in [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

```
'DD/M/YYYY h:mm a'
```

```js
var string = "14/2/2018 6:00 pm";
var date = moment(string, 'DD/M/YYYY h:mm a').toDate();
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find it here:
https://momentjs.com/docs/

For instance:

Unless you specify a time zone offset, parsing a string will create a date in the current time zone.

moment("2010-10-20 4:30",       "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");   // parsed as 4:30 local time
moment("2010-10-20 4:30 +0000", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"); // parsed as 4:30 UTC

=>

```
string += ' +0000';
moment(string, 'DD/M/YYYY h:mm a Z');
```